# What physical key maps to keycode 108 (VK_SEPARATOR)?

Tags: keyboard, keycode

Virtual Keycode 108 (**VK_SEPARATOR** *0x6c*) is defined as the "Separator" key.

My UK keyboard doesn't have this physical key.  It has two "/" keys but these are mapped to **VK_OEM_2** *0xBF* and **VK_DIVIDE** *0x6F*.

Which keyboards have a Separator key?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the full answer, but maybe it's good enough.

Numpads can have different layouts and the key assignments can be different. According to the [Microsoft Scancode Specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc) the numpad does have key 106 and 107 similarly to what you probably also find on your mentioned UK layout.

[image: MS Numpad Spec]

For key 107 the specification mentions:

> Keys 56 and 107 are used on Brazilian and some Far East keyboards. They [are] not available on US Keyboards.

The Brazilian keyboard does indeed have key 106 and 107 and more interestingly, 107 seems to be a `.` which one could also call a "separator"...

[image: Brazilian Numpad layout]

I'm sure if you continue looking, you'll find more similar layouts with the same amount of keys and similar key usages.

As a side note: The Apple keyboard also has the same number of keys, but arranged differently and has an additional equal sign.

[image: Apple Keyboard numpad]

Unfortunately, I don't have any of these layouts to actually test, what they return. Maybe for *some* layouts, the Win API will actually return `VK_SEPARATOR` instead of some `VK_OEM_XYZ`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but interpolating based on ASCII values, I get U+002C `,` (comma) for VK_SEPARATOR:

| virtual key code name | virtual key code number | ASCII code | character |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK_MULTIPLY | 0x6A | 0x2A | `*` |
| VK_ADD | 0x6B | 0x2B | `+` |
| VK_SEPARATOR | 0x6C | 0x2C? | `,`? |
| VK_SUBTRACT | 0x6D | 0x2D | `-` |
| VK_DECIMAL | 0x6E | 0x2E | `.` |
| VK_DIVIDE | 0x6F | 0x2F | `/` |